# OOP for parsing equations in java

Tags: java, oop

i have that code for parsing 1st and 2nd degree polynomial equations and I need help to make them at the same class and OOP.

**this code for 1st:**

```
 public class DegreeEquation {


  public static String coeff(String str, String regex) {
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher match = patt.matcher(str);
    // missing coefficient default
    String coeff = "+0"; 
    if(match.find()) 
        coeff = match.group(1);
    // always have sign, handle implicit 1
    return (coeff.length() == 1) ? coeff + "1" 
        : coeff;
} 

public static String[] quadParse(String arg) {
    String str = ("+" + arg).replaceAll("\\s", "");
    String a = coeff(str, "([+-][0-9]*)x(?!\\^)");
    String b = coeff(str, "([+-][0-9]+)(?!x)" );  

    double a1 = Double.parseDouble(a);
    double b1 = Double.parseDouble(b);
    double X = -b1/a1;
    String root1 = Double.toString(X);
    return new String[]{root1};
    }


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    String s;
    while ((s=r.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] pieces = quadParse(s);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pieces));
 }
}
```

**and this method for 2nd degree:**

```
public static String[] quadParse(String arg) {
    String str = ("+" + arg).replaceAll("\\s", "");

    String a = coeff(str, "([+-][0-9]*)x\\^2" );
    String b = coeff(str, "([+-][0-9]*)x(?!\\^)");
    String c = coeff(str, "([+-][0-9]+)(?!x)" );
    double a1 = Double.parseDouble(a);
    double b1 = Double.parseDouble(b);
    double c1 = Double.parseDouble(c);

   double dis = (Math.pow(b1, 2.0)) - (4 * a1 * c1);
   double d = Math.sqrt(dis);
   double X = 0,Y = 0; //root 1 & root 2, respectively

   if (dis > 0.0 || dis < 0.0 ) { 
       X = (-b1 + d)/(2.0 * a1 ); 
       Y = (-b1 - d)/(2.0 *a1);  
       String root1 = Double.toString(X);
       String root2 = Double.toString(Y);
       return new String[]{root1,root2};
   }
   else if (dis == 0.0){
       X = (-b1 + 0.0)/(2.0 * a1);//repeated root
       String root2 = Double.toString(X);
      return new String[]{root2}; 
   }
```

I want the program to know when the equation 1st degree (doesn't have x<sup>2</sup>) to run its method and same for 2nd degree at the same class.

Feel free to write any code as an example. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you want the solution to be object oriented? Your code doesn't look bad and a functional approach is suited to this problem. I'd just rename the `quadParse` functions to `quadParseFirstDegree` and `quadParseSecondDegree`; then create a new function `quadParse` that decides which of the two functions should be called by searching whether the string contains a `^2`.

Comment: @KuluLimpa yes because i want to make a program to solve any polynomial equation (1st ,2nd ,3rd degree) and i'm not good at OOP thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

How about this: create interface `Equation`

```
interface Equation {
    double[] solve();
    void fromString(String arg);
}
```

and 2 implementations `FirstDegreeEquation` and `SecondDegreeEquation`.

```
class FirstDegreeEquation implements Equation { ... }
class SecondDegreeEquation implements Equation { ... }
```

Then write class `Equations` with static method to get desired implementation by input string

```
class Equations {
        static Equation fromString(String str) { ... }
}
```

So later you read string, call `Equations.fromString` and solve it with `solve` method.

Here is the example code, where you will need to implement `toString` methods and condition that will identify degree of equation.

```
class FirstDegreeEquation implements Equation {
    double a = 0;
    double b = 0;

    public static String coeff(String str, String regex) {
        Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher match = patt.matcher(str);
        // missing coefficient default
        String coeff = "+0"; 
        if(match.find()) 
            coeff = match.group(1);
        // always have sign, handle implicit 1
        return (coeff.length() == 1) ? coeff + "1" 
            : coeff;
    } 

    public void fromString(String arg) {
        String str = ("+" + arg).replaceAll("\\s", "");
        String a = coeff(str, "([+-][0-9]*)x(?!\\^)");
        String b = coeff(str, "([+-][0-9]+)(?!x)" );  

        this.a = Double.parseDouble(a);
        this.b = Double.parseDouble(b);
    }

    public double[] solve() {
        return new double[]{ -b / a };
    }

    public String toString() {
        /* convert to string */
        return "";
    }
}

class SecondDegreeEquation implements Equation {
    double a = 0;
    double b = 0;
    double c = 0;

    public static String coeff(String str, String regex) {
        Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher match = patt.matcher(str);
        // missing coefficient default
        String coeff = "+0"; 
        if(match.find()) 
            coeff = match.group(1);
        // always have sign, handle implicit 1
        return (coeff.length() == 1) ? coeff + "1" : coeff;
    } 

    public void fromString(String arg) {
        String str = ("+" + arg).replaceAll("\\s", "");
        String a = coeff(str, "([+-][0-9]*)x\\^2" );
        String b = coeff(str, "([+-][0-9]*)x(?!\\^)");
        String c = coeff(str, "([+-][0-9]+)(?!x)" );
        this.a = Double.parseDouble(a);
        this.b = Double.parseDouble(b);
        this.c = Double.parseDouble(c);
    }

    public double[] solve() {
        double dis = (Math.pow(b, 2.0)) - (4 * a * c);
        double d = Math.sqrt(dis);
        double x = 0, y = 0; //root 1 & root 2, respectively

        if (dis > 0.0 || dis < 0.0 ) { 
            x = (-b + d)/(2.0 * a); 
            y = (-b - d)/(2.0 * a);
            return new double[]{x, y};
        } else if (dis == 0.0){
            x = (-b + 0.0)/(2.0 * a);//repeated root;
            return new double[]{x}; 
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String toString() {
        /* convert to string */
        return "";
    }
}

class Equations {
    static Equation fromString(String str) {
        Equation e = null;
        /* try to find ^2 */
        if(/*  */) {
            e = new SecondDegreeEquation();
        } else {
            e = new FirstDegreeEquation();
        }
        e.fromString(str);
        return e;
    }
}

class EquationsExample {  
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        String s;
        while((s=r.readLine()) != null) {
            Equation e = Equations.fromString(s);
            double[] solutions = e.solve();
            /* print solutions */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `toString()` as an interface method?

Comment: @SME_Dev stupid mistake, I corrected it, thank you! I just wanted to note that it would make sense to properly convert equation both ways (to and from string).

Comment: @NikolayKondratyev thanks for your answer and your help this is agood way to make it but i want to make this code on one class to be easy to add  this class with the entire program could u help me for that

Comment: @rk93 Your approach with only one class is wrong. It will be hard to extend this class and it's in no way OO design.

Comment: @rk93 Why do you want it like this?

Comment: @rk93 If your goal is to have everything in one file (opposed to everything in one class), then you should know that Java allows you to define multiple classes in the same file by nesting them. Something like: `class Equations { static class FirstDegreeEquation{ /* */} static class SecondDegreeEquation{/* */} /* */}` However, I don't know how much of a benefit this is, and - as far as I know - you couldn't define the interface in the same file. Maybe you could clarify what your goal is, as OOP and "all in one class" kind of doesn't work so well together.

Comment: @NikolayKondratyev because i'm working on an application that scan equations with OCR and then solving it so i need math work to be in one class to make it easy to me when combines all the code together

Comment: @NikolayKondratyev so that's your opinion !?

Comment: @rk93 At first plese move to the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77477/oop-for-parsing-equations-in-java) and describe your problem. Secondly this site is not for opinion-based and generate discussion questions.